# Django form only sending GET requests

Tags: python, django, forms, methods, request

I have this add page which uses a django form to get information which i am trying to store within "tasks" list and display in the todo html page.
i believe all my syntax is correct but it is not displaying the list of tasks when I submit the form.

on cmd it detects a GET request every time i submit the form, shouldnt it be saying post?

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms

tasks = []
class newTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="new task")
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "tasks/todo.html", {
        "tasks": tasks
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = newTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data["task"]
            tasks.append(task)
        else:
            return render(request, "tasks/add.html", {
                "form": form
            })
    return render(request, "tasks/add.html", {
        "form": newTaskForm
    })
```

add:

```
{% extends "tasks/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'tasks:add' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'tasks:home' %}">Veiw list</a>
{% endblock %}
```

todo:

```
{% extends "tasks/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <h1> To Do List</h1>
        <ul>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <li> {{ task }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'tasks:add' %}">Add items</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to add `method="post"` to your `form` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [@Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756552/django-form-only-sending-get-requests#comment116261816_65756552) suggested, you need to put **`method="post"`** as

```
{% block body %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'tasks:add' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'tasks:home' %}">Veiw list</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I can't believe I missed that.